# Is the choice of static and dynamic typing not visible to the programmers of the languages?

Tags: types, programming-languages, static-typing, dynamic-typing

From *Design Concepts in Programming Languages* by Turbak

> Although some **dynamically typed languages** have simple type markers (e.g., Perl variable names begin with a character that indicates the type of value: $ for
>   scalar values, @ for array values, and % for hash values (key/value pairs)), dynamically typed languages typically have
>   no explicit type annotations.
>
> The converse is true in **statically typed languages**,
>   where explicit type annotations are the norm. Most languages descended from
>   Algol 68 , such as Ada , C / C++ , Java , and Pascal , require that types be
>   explicitly declared for all variables, all data-structure components, and all function/procedure/method parameters and return values. However, some languages
>   (e.g., ML , Haskell , FX , Miranda ) achieve static typing without explicit type
>   declarations via a technique called type reconstruction or type inference.

**Question 1:** For dynamically typed languages which "have no explicit type annotations", do they need to infer/reconstruct the types/classes, by using some type/class reconstruction or type/class inference techniques,  as statically typed languages do?

**Question 2:**  The above quote says static or dynamic typing and   explicit or no type annotations can mix and match.

- Is the choice between  static and dynamic typing only internal to the implementations of programming languages, not visible to the programmers of the languages?
- Do programmers in programming languages only notice whether the languages use explicit type/class annotations or not, not whether the languages use static or dynamic typing?  Specifically, do  languages with explicit type/class annotations look the same to programmers, regardless of whether they are static or dynamic typing? Do  languages without explicit type/class annotations look the same to programmers, regardless of whether they are static or dynamic typing?

Thanks.

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. Of course languages look different. Some statically typed languages can look pretty close to dynamic ones and vice versa and also the opposite. Have you had a look at code in different languages and compared them…?

Answer (score 2):

> For dynamically typed languages which "have no explicit type annotations", do they need to infer/reconstruct the types/classes, by using some type/class reconstruction or type/class inference techniques, as statically typed languages do?

In statically typed languages, the types of things must be known statically. That's why they need type inference when there are no explicit type annotations. Dynamically typed languages don't need to (and generally can't) know the types until run time, so no type inference is necessary.

> Do programmers in programming languages only notice whether the languages use explicit type/class annotations or not, not whether the languages use static or dynamic typing?

Programmers will notice whether a language is dynamically or statically typed by observing whether type errors are detected statically or at runtime. Take the following program for example (adjusted to the particular language's syntax, of course):

```
var x = 4.2;
print("hello");
print("foo" / 4.2);
```

If the result of trying to (compile and) run this program is that you only get an error about not being able to divide a string by a number, the language is statically typed.

If the result is that "hello" is printed and *then* you get the error, the language is dynamically typed.

If the result is "hello" followed by NaN, the language is JavaScript.

Comment: Also - some languages, like perl, will evaluate a string as a number when used in a mathematical operation - if it looks like a number (or starts with what looks like a number), it is that number. If not, it's zero.  "foo" would evaluate as 0, so `print "foo"/4.2` is equivalent to `print 0/4.2`. there would be no error, output would be `0`.  (`print 4.2/ "foo"` would be a divide-by-zero error, of course).  also, perl has a useful definition of what a number looks like: e.g. `5.2x5` evaluates as 5.2....but `5.2e5` evaluates as 520000. nice.

Answer (score 2):

The difference—generally speaking—between dynamically typed and statically typed languages is that they execute differently. A statically typed language is typically compiled to very efficient machine code (or something close to it). This means for a piece of code like this:

```
foo = bar + baz
```

Lower-level code needs to be generated that actually does what this code is expressing. What exactly this code is expressing depends on the details; say in this hypothetical language `+` can be used both to add numbers and to concatenate strings. Those are two very different operations for which different machine code must be generated, so the statically typed language needs to know what types are involved here and what code must be generated.

In a dynamically typed language, all this would resolve at runtime instead of at compile time. At runtime, the program would check what types `bar` and `baz` are and choose the appropriate operation to run. `bar` and `baz` could be different types every time this line of code runs and could produce a different result every time.

So, dynamically typed languages don't need to know types of *variables* at compile time, they will act based on the type of the *values* at runtime. Generally speaking, in static languages the *variables* (the name `bar`) have types which at runtime will only hold values of that type, while in dynamic languages variables are just names and the values assigned to them can have any type.

> Is the choice between static and dynamic typing only internal to the implementations of programming languages, not visible to the programmers of the languages? [..]

- statically typed languages can catch certain classes of errors at compile time (e.g. "`+` operation doesn't make sense for variables `bar` and `baz`, which you declared as `int` and `str`"), which would only surface at runtime in dynamic languages
- consequently, dynamic languages often depend a lot more on unit test suites than statically typed languages
- as noted above, `bar + baz` may produce entirely different results every time it's executed in dynamic languages, whereas it will always produce the same type in static languages; that alone enables very different programming styles
- "generics" are something many dynamic programmers don't even know how to spell, while it's a huge helper in statically typed languages (in a nutshell, generics allows something like `bar + baz` to return different types even in static languages, but it still takes some type finagling compared to dynamic languages)
- static languages still need type annotations (and no matter how good the inference mechanism is, you *will* encounter them sooner or later), so static languages do look different than dynamic ones

There's probably a lot more to be listed here, but in summary: a programmer *will* notice the difference.

Note that the lines tend to blur over time: dynamic languages tend to grow more and more type annotations over time, since the error checking it enables is arguably pretty vital for any halfway complex project; static languages OTOH tend to try to minimise the necessary annotations with better and better inference over time, to save the programmer the extra keystrokes.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to peek into the future...

> Question 1: For dynamically typed languages which "have no explicit type annotations", do they need to infer/reconstruct the types/classes

No, they don't need to infer in the classical sense, but soon or later they will do it anyway: when a variable is accessed and involved in some calculation/manipulation.

Don't forget also about constants. If I write:

```
avar = "Goofy"
```

some type of inference is already there, to understand that avar should contain a string of five chars.
Later, when executing for example

```
avar = avar + " blah"   // append some char
```

the variable avar has some marker saying "this is a string"; by inference (what is " blah"?) the interpreter determines that two strings must be concatenated. I see, here, both inference and reconstruct...

Peek to the future: a compiler (even for interpreted languages - Python for example can be compiled to .pyc) can get big advantages in inferring correctly a few things. The instruction above, "avar = avar + ' blah'", can be compiled to something which already knows that we are chaining two strings, and hence is faster.

> Is the choice between static and dynamic typing only internal to the implementations of programming languages, not visible to the programmers of the languages?

These are two faces of the coin; what is good for one could be not good for someone else. Static typed languages are presumably always faster, but are more verbose to write (require more typing - pun intended). Dynamic typing is handy, but slower and can lead to errors at runtime. I think that the choice is made looking *exactly* at the final user of the language, so I think NO: the choice between static and dynamic is very visible to the user!

BUT: there is a midway, namely "duck typing", which can (should) be a static typing but more intelligent and less verbose to write. It can not solve (coins always will have two sides), but it can help.

> Do programmers only notice whether the languages use explicit type/class annotations or not, not whether the languages use static or dynamic typing?

In theory, the answer could be yes: the programmer should only be aware of explicit typing or automatic typing the language exposes to the user. But in practice, programmers are intelligent, often they run the programs they write, and sometimes they even do debugging. When running and, even more, when debugging, the differences between static and dynamic typing arise. This is because programmers are intelligent and computers are stupid (there are exceptions, but not normally).

Again, a peek to the future: may be languages will come which will be internally statically typed, but able to present themselves quasi dynamically typed. Good. The contrary should not happen: who wants a verbose, statically typed language, that in the end is actually dynamic?

Just my two cents.

Comment: In that `"Goofy"` example, there’s no *inference* going on. Inference refers to “you haven’t told me what type `avar` is, but since you’re assigning a string to it, I’ll infer it’s a string”. In a dynamic language, that’s not happening. `avar` is a typeless name. The value `"Goofy"` is obviously a string, since it’s a string literal. That doesn’t need to be inferred, that’s parsed from the source.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201673/discussion-on-answer-by-linuxfan-is-the-choice-of-static-and-dynamic-typing-not).